# Centrex/Asterisk with multiple distincts AD

Tags: active-directory, ldap, asterisk

A little bit of context, I'm currently working on a school project, and I have to set up a "Centrex" style Asterisk server, preparing and tunning thing to reach a production ready installation.

So far I've found informations about coupling your Asterisk to 1 LDAP/AD, with an LDIF file and some configuration of the Asterisk server.

But is it even feasible to use multiple distinct LDAP/AD ? Or are you supposed to connect to only one LDAP/AD per Asterisk server ?

If possible, how much of an hassle would it be to set up ?

I am running CentOS 7.7 with a fresh install of Asterisk 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asterisk is opensource soft. Since almost nobody need connect 2 or more AD to server, this feature have no implementation.

There is 2 possible solution for this

1) read and modifiy ldap driver in asterisk. Just copy/paste to make second with other name. Require c/c++ programming experience

2) read openldap documentation and do do changes in it. Like make sub-trees etc. Require openldap/AD administration experience.

Both seams like require advanced experience.

Comment: I have no experience in c/c++, and openldap seems over my current level, thanks for the info though, I'll look into that later when I have a better understanding of the whole thing.

Comment: Other options is create N vps in each put own ldap and asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that typically, LDAP-aware applications only connect to *one* LDAP tree at a time. This has to do with differences in search locations, schema, etc.

Looking at the Asterisk LDAP [integration docs](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/LDAP+Realtime+Driver), it looks like it follows the same pattern: it can integrate with one LDAP tree.

If you really want to link multiple ADs / LDAP directory trees, you might be able to use [LDAP referrals](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP%20Referral) but that requires quite a lot of knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the information, after looking at your links I can definitely say that it's way over my current level.
I'll look into containers and VM solutions instead.